# Estimating conditional probability of bernoulli data

Tags: conditional-probability, inference, bernoulli-distribution

Assume I have $i=1,\dots,N$ fathers, each with $j=1,\dots,n_i>0$ sons. Now there is a binary event $A_{i,j}$ with outcomes 1 and 0 and the respective probabilities $p$ and $1-p$. Now I want to assess whether it is more likely for the event to happen for a son, conditional on the event happening for any of the father's other sons (disregarding the timing of each event) in comparison to the unconditional probability. I have formulated these respective probabilities

$P(A_{i,j}=1)$

$P(A_{i,j}=1|\sum_{l \neq j}A_{i,l}>1)$

Using Bayes' theorem, I have that

$P(A_{i,j}=1|\sum_{l \neq j}A_{i,l}>1) = \frac{P(A_{i,j}=1,\sum_{l \neq j}A_{i,l}>1)}{P(\sum_{l \neq j}A_{i,l}>1)} = \frac{P(\sum_{l}A_{i,l}>2)}{P(\sum_{l}A_{i,l}>1+A_{i,j})}$

$P(\sum_{l}A_{i,l}>2)$ can be estimated by $\sum_i\Big((S_i-2>0)\Big)/N$ where $S_i$ is the number of events amongst father $i$:s sons (and $(S_i-2>0)$ equals 1 if true and 0 otherwise)

And $P(\sum_{l}A_{i,l}>1+A_{i,j})$ can be estimated by

$\sum_i\Big(\frac{\sum_j(S_i-1-a_{i,j}>0)}{n_i}\Big)/N$

Does this seem reasonable and/or is there a better/correct way to assess the problem: whether it is more likely for the event to happen for a son, conditional on the event happening for any of the father's other sons?

Any help/references is appreciated!